# How should I use deprive?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

When you want to say *take one's life*, that is, *kill someone*, using the verb *deprive*, do you say *deprive one's life*?

According to dictionaries, *deprive* is a transitive verb and its use is 'deprive A of B'.

Then, the possible expression could be *deprive him or her of life*. Is that right?

Comment: easy reference :http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/deprive

Comment: Sadly, the dictionary entry does not explain whether '*deprive him or her of life.*' is correct, as the OP wanted to know. If not, why?

Answer (score 3):

It would be

> deprive one of one's life

Yes, deprive is a transitive verb. *him* or *her* need to be repeated.

One could also deprive someone of someone else's something, not necessarily one's own, like support, benefit, etc., as in

> deprive him of his father's support

By the way, it's better to avoid the use of *one* and substitute it with something more substantial.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see. The comment on the use of 'one' is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's nothing wrong with the grammaticality of the expression **deprive someone of their life**, it doesn't sound natural English. I wouldn't use it. You can use **end** or **take someone's life** instead.

Comment: I thought the same, too. However, I think OP's question is not about that anyway.